# How to create required fields for custom post types in Wordpress 3?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am creating a custom post type called article and I want to make a field called genre to be required. Is this possible?

Comment: can you be a little more clear with "field called genre"... if you want something like categories or tags it is possible to add custom taxonomies with custom post types.

Comment: The field genre is a custom taxonomy type being placed in the custom post type article. I can do both successfully. I am asking how to make the genre required. It should be given a value.

Comment: Hello Giljed, I came here with the same question in mind. If you got an answer to your question, please let me know. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($req) echo "aria-required='true'";
```